# Error message (due to Chinese characters?)

Tags: r

new to R.

I ran my program and received an error message.  I think it's due to Chinese characters in the values.  Is there a way to bypass this?

message:

```
> DFnew2 <- DFnew %>%
+   group_by(Vendor, `Product name`) %>%
+   summarise(freq = sum(`Product name`))
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `freq`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `freq` is `sum(`Product name`)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Vendor = "Cassava", Product name = "Cassava - “Dino”<U+725B><U+808B><U+6392><U+5957><U+9910> Beef \"Dino\" Rib Dinner Meal Kit".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

[data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNXYZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in the relative frequency of the product names within a Vendor, try:

```
DFnew2 <- DFnew %>%
   group_by(Vendor, `Product name`) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) %>%            # stop here for frequency
   mutate(freq = count/sum(count))       # stop here for relative frequency
```

At the moment, it looks like you are trying to pass `sum()` a character. For example, `sum("a")` will produce the same error you mention.